# Clone selects and keep on cloning or deleting a cloned select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, count, clone

I am having problems with cloning selects and deleting them.

What do I want:

1. When changing a select, I want to clone the select so there's a new select.
2. Changing a cloned select will add a new select too.
3. Selects can be removed
4. In total there can be max 5 selects but at least 1 select
5. Update labels with increasing numbers. If one in the middle will be removed, all selects get new label numbers.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teezii/24v74rLo/)

What goes wrong:

- After cloning you can also delete selects. It can be any select, but there must always 1 select that can't be removed. Removing clones must update the numbers as well.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectsCount = 1;
    $('.box label').text('Selector ' + (selectsCount++));
    $('.box select').on('change', function() {
        if (selectsCount < 5) {
            var cloned =    $('.box').last().clone(true).insertAfter($(this).parents('.box:last'));
            cloned;
            cloned.find("label").text('test Selector ' + (selectsCount++));
        }
    });

    $(".cancelSelect").on('click', function() {
        var parentBox = $(this).parents('.box');
        parentBox.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        parentBox.remove();
    });
});
```

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teezii/24v74rLo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `true` as argument in `jQuery.clone(true)`

> [**`.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] )`**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements.

Also `--selectsCount;` if you remove `select` input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateLabel() {
    $('.selectBox label').each(function(index) {
      this.textContent = 'test Selector ' + (index + 1);
    });
  }
  var selectsCount = 1;
  $('.box label').text('Selector ' + (selectsCount++));
  $('.box select').on('change', function() {
    if (selectsCount < 5) {
      var cloned = $('.box').last().clone(true).insertAfter($(this).parents('.box:last'));
      cloned.find("label").text('test Selector ' + (selectsCount++));
      updateLabel();
    }
  });

  $(".cancelSelect").on('click', function() {
    if ($('.selectBox').length > 1) {
      var parentBox = $(this).parents('.box');
      parentBox.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
      parentBox.remove();
      --selectsCount;
      updateLabel();
    } else {
      alert('Can not delete all');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label,
select {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.selectBox {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.cancelSelect {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectorClones">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="selectBox">
      <label></label>
      <select class="select1" name="select1">
        <option value="first">First choice</option>
        <option value="second">Second choice</option>
        <option value="third">Third choice</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='cancelSelect'>
      X
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so close yet so far away! So one problem left and that's 1 select must stay and can't be removed + updating numbers after removing a select.

Comment: Now we can delete all the selects. What I want is that you can delete all selects but 1 but it doesn't matter which ones you delete. Deleting the selects must update the number again.

Comment: @Teezii — Are you talking about the `label` ?

Comment: 2 things: the label must be updated with the numbers. But I can delete all the selects. I want to keep always 1 select

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(document).on('change','.box select', function() {
    //Find total select box length
    var selectsCount = parseInt($('.box select').length);
    if (selectsCount < 5) {
      var cloned = $('.box').last().clone().insertAfter($(this).parents('.box:last'));
      cloned;
      //Update select box length
      selectsCount = parseInt($('.box select').length);
      cloned.find("label").text('Selector ' + (selectsCount));
    }
    //Update the select box label
    var _selectsCount = 1;
    $('.box label').each(function(){
      $(this).text('Selector ' + (_selectsCount++));
    });
  });
  
  //Remove the select box on remove selectbox
  $(document).on('click',".cancelSelect", function() {
    var parentBox = $(this).parents('.box');
    parentBox.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    parentBox.remove();
    //Update the select box label
    var _selectsCount = 1;
    $('.box label').each(function(){
      $(this).text('Selector ' + (_selectsCount++));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label,
select {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.selectBox {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cancelSelect {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectorClones">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="selectBox">
      <label>Selector 1</label>
      <select class="select1" name="select1">
        <option value="first">First choice</option>
        <option value="second">Second choice</option>
        <option value="third">Third choice</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='cancelSelect'>
      X
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Rahul!

Comment: @Teezii You will able to check in snippet that select box can be cloned up to 5 and on deletion or on addition of any select box any where the label of select box will be updated.

Comment: @Rayon Removed it. But I have commented after I have successfully solved SO's problem.